# Can you access a non-static class property statically in php?

Tags: php, static

Let's say I have the following class:

```
class A {
    public $Foo;
    public $Foo2;

    public static function $Current;

    public static function setCurrent($Foo, $Foo2) {
       self::$Current=new A($Foo, $Foo2);
    }

    public function __construct($Foo, $Foo2) {
       $this->Foo=$Foo;
       $this->Foo2=$Foo2;
    }

}
```

If I write the following code:

```
  A::setCurrent(1,2);
```

is there any possible way, to later use `A::$Foo`, and get the content of `A::$Current->Foo` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some errors.

`public static setCurrent` should be `public static function setCurrent` and `public __construct` should be `public function __construct`.

You can't use `A::$Foo` because this is not a static property. But you can call `A::$Current->Foo`.

But the design of the class is poor in my opinion. You should use encapsulation. And I don't understand why you would want to create an instance and then place it in a class property.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out, this is not my exact use case, I just wanted a more simple code, for easier understanding. The use case would be the following: there will always be a default `A` class defined, which I want to have quick access to, without storing the initialized object as a global variable and everything, but there can be more `A` classes defined throughout the code. I know that as it is written, it won't work, I am thinking about using the magic get somehow, to achieve my desired result.